Is this ceiling crack a hazard?
I just moved into my boyfriend’s house that he bought in late 2022. Noticing all kinds of cracks in the ceilings and walls, plus lots of uneven floors. This one is the most concerning to me - it’s in the living room ceiling, which is below our bedroom. I believe the crack is along where the previous owners put on an addition to the house, as in there was an exterior wall here in the past. I also noticed the floor above seems to dip at the same place. I’ve been nervous about sleeping above it or hanging out in the living room, but my boyfriend insists it’s nothing to worry about. Is it an urgent concern or is he right?
Pictures: https://imgur.com/a/Lusnlaz

Most cracks like that are common and not something to be worried about, but with the dips and not knowing if the addition was done right, it is something you want someone(an expert) to look at.

One immediate concern is cracks in the textured ceiling can lead to falling plaster -- not a great safety hazard, though. It would be worthwhile to have a structural engineer or other qualified person inspect the house -- for your safety, peace of mind, and for buying insurance.

Looks like a drywall joint crack to me.

The cracks in the ceiling are cosmetic. It is a drywall separation at the seems. Easy to fix with some drywall tape and mud.
I do not know about the floors without more information.
